# Regular expression (lex flex): strings separated by double bars

Tags: regex, yacc, lex

I'd like to write a regular expression rule (for lex, but general regex should be okay) like the following:

```
arbitrary-length-string || arbitrary-length-string
```

The string can contains all characters but "||" symbol. It may contain '|'.

So, basically need a regex that captures **all strings but "||"**. But, stuck at this step.

Can somebody give me a hint how to write regex for such string?

Comment: Are you sure?  So, if your input file contains no `||`, you want all the data in a single string, but if the file contains one `||`, you want all the stuff before the first `||` as a string, and everything after it, including subsequent `||`, to be the third string (with `||` as the second one, of course)?  I think that's unlikely, so you should specify the context better — probably.

Comment: If no "||", then yacc will reject the input. If there are two "||", this is also an error.

Comment: You're right. Basically I want to take all the stuff except for "||". In general string functions (C++ or python whatever), this will be much easier. Just find "||". That's it. But, doing so with RE is a bit tricky.

Comment: You probably need 'trailing context', which is prefixed by a slash, IIRC.  So, `…some-regex…/\|\|` will be the basic structure.  The suggestion by [templatetypedef](http://stackoverflow.com/users/501557/templatetypedef) in his [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21006990/15168) looks plausible for what I marked as `…some-regex`.  I'm still not convinced this is something that you should be using Flex (or even a regex) for, but you've not explained the context in which this rule might appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A string that doesn't contain || can be thought of as a collection of strings made of individual characters that are then separated by vertical bars. For example, strings like

```
ab|cd|ef|gh
|ab|cd|ef
```

etc. follow this pattern. These strings

- begin (optionally) with a nonempty string,
- then consist of any number of copies of a vertical bar followed by a nonempty string, and
- optionally end with a vertical bar.

Assuming the only characters permitted are "a" and "|", one regex for this is

> (a+)?(\|a+)*\|?

(I'm using \| to stand for the | character, since it needs to be escaped). I think you can then write a regex for your overall requirement by just concatenating two copies of that regular expression with "||" in the middle.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's extremely helpful comment. I'm trying it.